# Error:java.lang.NullPointerException in android

Tags: android

[2011-02-18 23:41:16 - ddms]null

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

What kind of error is this..All xml files are having error suddenly like below..

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Premature end of file.
- error: Error parsing XML: no 
 element found
```

thank you,

Comment: Post your Java and XML codes too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first group of errors generally mean that there's a problem in the communication between ddms and the emulator you have fired up. I've found those errors to be generally harmless.

The XML errors sound like you should restart Eclipse (if that's what you're using), or else clean your project. Something got out of sync. (If the problem persists, post an example of the XML that's generating the errors.)

Answer (score 0):

This error started showing up for me after I experimented with deleting files from the AVD. I must of deleted something that was important. I got rid of the error by closing the emulator and deleting the AVD in Eclipse and then recreating and running it.