# DDMS : java.lang.nullPointerException at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume

Tags: android, android-emulator

i has create android_2.1 emulator , 
when ever i rum any application , after some seconds CONSOLE will generate error like that

```
[2011-09-23 21:53:43 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

is any type of error and can have any solution of this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .. errors generally mean that there's a problem in the
>   communication between ddms and the emulator you have fired up.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038253/errorjava-lang-nullpointerexception-in-android).