# Lacking errors messages with Android Phonegap plugin

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova, adt

I'm updating a Phonegap 2.9.0 iOS plugin to work with a new Android/iOS Phonegap 3.4.0 project.

Previously for iOS only I was just making the **.h/.m** files and adding the `<feature>` tag to the **config.xml** file, now I'm using the **CLI** and a GIT repo for the plugin.

When I add my plugin via the CLI and run the app from Eclipse on a USB device, the Phonegap Javascript doesn't run, and I don't get anything useful in the **console** or **logcat**.

This is the console output:

```
[2014-05-29 09:23:17 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:164)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:739)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2014-05-29 09:23:17 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:164)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:739)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

The HTML loads, but the `onDeviceReady` event doesn't fire. I can add a `setInterval` and append text to the body with `innerHTML += '<br />log'` and that shows up, so it just seems to be the Phonegap JS that's failing.

I found another SO post pointing out that a plugin can cause this, and if I remove my plugin the JS runs.

So I know I've got my plugin wrong, and that's fine, first time writing a CLI installed plugin I can fix it, what I want to know is can I get any more useful information from the console, like a file, line number, type of problem instead of just `NullPointerException`

Comment: Found my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5038269/2617398) to the same problem... FYI